# How to disable my sound effect for all my button?

Tags: javascript, android, audio, soundeffect

I have different buttons and each of them have their own sound effects.
for enable my sound effect I used this class:

`enter code here`

```
public class Effects {
private static final String TAG = Effects.class.toString();

private static final Effects INSTANCE = new Effects();


public static final int SOUND_1 = 1;
public static final int SOUND_2 = 2;

private Effects() {

}

public static Effects getInstance() {
    return INSTANCE;
}

private SoundPool soundPool;
private HashMap<Integer, Integer> soundPoolMap;
int priority = 1;
int no_loop = 0;
private int volume;
float normal_playback_rate = 1f;

private Context context;

public void init(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
    soundPool = new SoundPool(4, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 100);
    soundPoolMap = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
    soundPoolMap.put(SOUND_1, soundPool.load(context, R.raw.laser, 1));

    AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager) context.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
    volume = audioManager.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_SYSTEM);
}

public void playSound(int soundId) {
    Log.i(TAG, "!!!!!!!!!!!!!! playSound_1 !!!!!!!!!!");
    soundPool.play(soundId, volume, volume, priority, no_loop, normal_playback_rate);

}
```

then I identify this class in my activity in this way:

```
 Effects.getInstance().init(this);
```

an then when I click my button , it works correcty.

```
 Effects.getInstance().playSound(Effects.SOUND_1);
```

now I want another button to disable these sound effects.
when I click my disable button to disable :

```
button(my button's name).setSoundEffectsEnabled(false);
```

it doesn't work at all.
what's the problem?

Comment: `it doesn't work at all` - a "shrug" report.  By the way, bad memory leak if you are passing an `Activity` as your `Context`.

Comment: If you're calling playSound in this class to play a sound effect, of course calling setSoundEffectEnabled has no effect-  you're doing your own sound effect, and playSound() isn't checking the value of any setting.  Why wouldn't it play?